# Density function involving unit step function

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution function

$$  P_{X}(x) = \left[ 1 - \exp(-2x) \right] u(x)$$

where $u( \cdot ) $ is the unit step function.

Calculate the PDF $p_{x}(x)$

In order to find the PDF we need to differentiate

$$ p_{X}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} P_{X}(x) $$

so then if we use the product rule

$$   \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))  = f(x)g^{'}(x) + f^{'}(x)g(x) $$

we have

$$ \left[ 1 - \exp(-2x) \right] \delta(x) + \left[ 2 \exp(-2x)\right] u(x)  $$

My question is suppose we were given the pdf on getting the CDF so.

$$ P_{X}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \left[ 1 - \exp(-ux) \right] \delta(u) + \left[ 2 \exp(-2u)\right] \textbf{u}(x) \textrm{d}u $$

I don't know much about those functions in integrals.

Comment: @drhab edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

First observe that a random variable $X$ that is equipped with this CDF is almost surely positive. This is a direct consequence of the fact that $P_X(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$.

Then we can just state that a PDF (if it exists) can be taken to have value $0$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and for really finding a PDF it is enough to look at the values that are taken on $(0,\infty)$. Doing so we find that the function takes value $2e^{-2x}$ on $(0,\infty)$.

It is really not necessary to use the product-rule here. It is just a matter of discerning cases: $x\leq0$ and $x>0$.

2)

If $f(x)$ functions as PDF of some distribution then the corresponding CDF is the function:$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(u)du$$